# How to plot already transformed data by only tranforming the scale (x or y axis) but not data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, coordinate-transformation

I have a data from my RNAseq data. I trying to plot log2FoldChange against the genome position.

```
ggplot(result.withGeneMap.asDF, aes(x=start, y= log2FoldChange)) +
  ggtitle("Allele Balance Plot") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.position = "bottom") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(-4, -2, 2, 4) , 
         color = c("red", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "red")) +
  geom_point(aes(x=start, y= log2FoldChange, 
             color = sig), position=position_jitter(w=0.1,h=0), size = 1)
```

which gives me:

[image]

The data on y-axis is already on `log2` scale. Everything is good, except I want to calibrate only the scale on y-axis at log2 level, not the data. 
Whenever I am using `scale_y_continous(trans = ...)` or `coord_trans(x = "log2", y="log2")` the already transformed data gets further `log2` transformed giving me.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't quite get what you want.  Are you saying you want the labels to be for the unlogged scaled?

Comment: The data is log2 scaled (in a csv input) but you can see the y-axis isn't log2 scaled. So, that is the problem. How do I plot already scaled data? There was a method using `scaled=TRUE` but can't find it.

Comment: You could just un-transform the pre-transformed data for plotting, i.e. plot `2 ** log2FoldChange` and apply the scale transformations normally

Comment: Alternatively, if you just plot `log2FoldChange` you can back-transform the axis breaks and labels; something like this: `scale_y_continuous(breaks = function(x) seq(floor(min(x)), ceiling(max(x))), labels = function(x) 2 ^ x)`